# Power System Design for BLDC control - why not use a DC/DC convertor?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, control, brushless-dc-motor

So I have experienced the usage of a BLDC motor to spin a propeller. The electrical design ensured the bus voltage was such as to bring the motor to a good operating regime given the Kv, etc. However, when the propeller is required to spin slower (or when the torque required to spin it at a certain RPM decreases, maybe due to less dense air, for example), PWM is used to "throttle" the voltage and change the torque-speed curves.

I have a couple questions about the system design:

1. Why worry about the voltage for the rest of the system? Why not just use a DC-DC convertor just before the motor unit? Similarly, why not use a DC-DC convertor instead of PWM control, and have a steady voltage of the average voltage instead of a duty-cycle of voltage to get the right average?
2. An addendum to that question is: on the flip side, why not just have a much higher bus voltage than required (if possible to provide), and then use PWM to achieve any desired voltage below bus? What's the point of "getting the supply voltage right" on the bus? Wouldn't this decrease i2r losses and decrease cable weight? Additionally, wouldn't this mean the range of operation is much higher for the motor, with no worries of running out of available voltage should we want to go higher?

Comment: "why not use a DC-DC convertor instead of PWM?" How do you thdink the DC-DC convertor works? ... PWM.

Comment: *Implement a PWM = a few discrete components. Easy, very low chance of failure. *Implement a SMPS: controller chip, input MOSFET, custom transformer, specialty rectifiers, opto/feedback, custom PCB, tuning and tweaking... much more difficult, costly, and prone to issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few weird things about the post so I am just going to point them all out just to be safe.

> Why not just use a DC-DC convertor just before the motor unit?

I don't know what you are referring to exactly when you say "motor unit" but if you are referring to just the motor, then do you realize that a brushless motor driver is required to drive a brushless motor (i.e. just connecting a DC-DC converter onto a BLDC motor will lock up the motor and burn it out)?

> Similarly, why not use a DC-DC convertor instead of PWM control, and have a steady voltage of the average voltage instead of a duty-cycle of voltage to get the right average?

Do you realize a brushless motor driver and DC-DC converter both used PWM?

---

Do you realize that a brushless motor driver is actually a DC-AC converter? optimized for high-power with less emphasis on a good quality output (since the motor isn't very picky) with features added to synchronize the output to the motor so it commutates properly?

The fact a BLDC motor driver is a form of converter means that it can, in a way, tone down the voltage for the motor.

So your question should really be why can't you just supply the BLDC  driver with a very high voltage and have it drive the motor at a reduced voltage?

There are a few reasons:

1. Things run less efficiently when the input and output voltage are very different (in this case, very high input voltages relative to output voltages requires very low duty cycles which don't run well or efficiently).
2. BLDC motor drivers are optimized for high power and the expense of output quality since the motor isn't very picky. Improving output quality would decrease efficiency which increases heat and size due to increased PWM frequency and filtering components that need to handle all the power.
3. It is harsher on the equipment when the input and output voltages are very different.
   Without a good high quality filter (which is big and heavy if it needs to handle motor power levels) PWM doesn't actually completely hide the extra high input voltage (or the extra high peak currents that result from it). In mechanical terms, a high input voltage is like saying every time I shove something I shove it with a force of 10,000 Newtons. So to shove something more gently I apply quick, short bursts of 10,000N. That's what PWM is. You can see that it doesn't make for a very gentle or smooth ride if you don't have good shock absorbers (which is what the filter is).

This applies both PWMing to step down the power before the motor driver, and the motor driver PWMing to drive the motor at a reduced voltage level than the driver's input voltage.

So if you have an easy means of getting the input voltage close to, but above the output voltage (since it is easier to step down a voltage than it is to step up a voltage and the fundamental BLDC driver design only steps down voltage) then you might as well do it since everything will run better. For example, just swapping out the battery for a lower voltage one truly provides a smooth, clean voltage rather than crudely trying to simulate one through PWM which ends up being peaky.

> Additionally, wouldn't this mean the range of operation is much higher for the motor, with no worries of running out of available voltage should we want to go higher?

Why would you want to feed the motor more voltage than it can handle? The max voltage of RC motors (where the expected operating voltages are far below the voltage rating of the insulation materials used) tends to be based on the the voltage that causes a no-load RPM that will cause the motor to throw its bearings.

Supplying the motor driver from too high a voltage could still burn out the motor even at reduced power levels, especially if the output quality is not high due to the peaky nature of the 10,000N pushing mentioned above that is representative of PWM.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response to a question from a not very well informed person. I'm looking at this from a mechanical design, with no electrical assistance (yet). When I say "motor unit" I meant controller + motor. So, "why not have high voltage from batteries to the motor unit, then step down using DC-DC just before the controller, to get close to operating voltage", and THEN use additional PWM as part of the driver/controller to regulate voltage as required in a narrower range?

Comment: @spaceprops That would boil down to *how* you are "ensuring the bus voltage" is at a good level.

Comment: I THINK you basically answered my question in the second half. But just to make sure I got it right...I can essentially have a 200V bus, step down to 100V if that's the voltage the motor nominally wants (say, 80-100V is the rating) cause of your 3 reasons, and then achieve torque-speed curves anywhere below that by changing the voltage using PWM from the controller? E.g. V=100 V curve, then V=70V curve, then back to V=90V?

Comment: @spaceprops Sort of. I'm not sure if you will understand this next part but the motor actually doesn't care much about the voltage and doesn't run off the voltage. It runs off the voltage. Sure, the transistors in the motor driver or the insulation in the motor can be blown out if the voltage is too high, but if it's not then the motor is probably fine. It only cares about the current. The current is what actually matters, but voltages are given instead since voltage sources are easier to build, use and understand so things are rated that way. [cont...]

Comment: [cont...] without a good high quality filter (which is big and heavy if it needs to handle motor power levels) PWM doesn't actually completely hide the extra high input voltage (or the extra high peak currents that result from it). In mechanical terms, a high input voltage is like saying every time I shove something I shove it with a force of 10,000 Newtons. So to shove something more gently I apply quick, short bursts of 10,000N. That's what PWM is. You can see that it doesn't make for a very gentle or smooth ride if you don't have good shock absorbers (which is what the filter is).

Comment: [cont...] This applies both PWMing to step down the power before the motor driver, and the motor driver PWMing to drive the motor at a reduced voltage level than the driver's input voltage.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense qualitatively. My concern with the DC-DC was I assumed it was another source of inefficiency, which is the premium for this project. I was trying to avoid that, but it sounds like the bumpy control might end up being worse. Sounds like a good solution is to match the battery voltage to the highest voltage curve required by the BLDC motor...at a cost of heavier cables and i2r transmission losses. [..cont]

Comment: @spaceprops Yeah. Previously when I said "*That would boil down to how you are ensuring the bus voltage" is at a good level.*", a battery is one that is better since you are *truly* applying a lower voltage that is actually smooth, not peaky, and gentle, not trying to crudely simulate one with PWM.

Comment: [Cont..] regarding your voltage vs current thing -  I actually think I realized that when dealing with the thermal limits of the motor. I saw no reason (other than transistors blowing out, etc.) to not operate at twice the rated voltage, as long as we kept the current below the rated I_max. Is this true? Imagine there's no load on the motor - so it's drawing very little current, can I just run it twice the voltage and get twice the speed with no harm?

Comment: @spaceprops As long as you don't throw the bearings. The voltage rating of model RC motors tends to be based on the voltage that causes the no-load RPM where the motor will throw its bearings, not the actual voltage of the insulation (which is >300V).

Comment: Whoa good to know. Thanks a lot, this has been phenomenally helpful.

Comment: Isn't the motor winding already a filter by itself?

Comment: @user253751 It is, but it's usually not enough to filter out large peaky currents from due to overly high input voltages